# Some issues with Java Robot class

Tags: java, awtrobot

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class sample
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws AWTException {

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        WindowElement StopTime = handler.findElementByAutomationID(Timer, "2049");
        handler.click(StopTime);
        handler.setfocus(StopTime);

        int StopTimeMinute = Minute + 8 ;
        String val = "";
        val = String.valueOf(StopTimeMinute);
        sendkeys(val);
    }

    public static void sendkeys(String text)
    {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            String val = text.toUpperCase();
            for(int i=0;i<val.length();i++) {
                robot.keyPress(Character.getNumericValue(val.charAt(i)));
            }
        } catch(java.awt.AWTException exc) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am getting source not found error if I try to send variable to robot key event method. => 89. Java robot is failing to press key. Can  anyone tell me how I can pass variable to Robot.KeyPress(code)?

And whats wrong in the below code?
Robot.KeyPress(VK_SHIFT) is working fine but Robot.KeyPress(code) is throwing the below Error.

```
WRobotPeer.keypress int(line) : not available [native method]
Source not found.
```

I even tried sending integer as an argument still same issue.

```
public static void StopMinute(int StopMinute) throws AWTException{
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.delay(20);
    robot.keyPress(StopMinute);
    robot.keyRelease(StopMinute);
}
```

Can anyone suggest me with this. Robot.KeyPress(Code)

Comment: Post the complete stack trace, not just the top line.

Answer (score 1):

The method getNumericValue() on Character returns a Unicode code point for that character. `Character.getNumericValue('A')` returns 10 for instance, whereas `KeyEvent.VK_A` returns the ascii value of 65. The latter value is used for the AWT Robot, not the first.

Instead of itering over `val.length()`, do `val.toCharArray()` instead, and iterate over that. And then pass `(int)charArray[i]` to robot keyPress.